# scikit-learn OpenMP libsvm

Tags: python, openmp, libsvm, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn SVC to classify some data. I would like to increase the training performance.

> clf = svm.SVC(cache_size=4000, probability=True, verbose=True)

Since sckikit-learn interfaces with libsvm and libsvm uses OpenMp I was hoping that:

> export OMP_NUM_THREADS=16

would run on multiple cores.
Unfortunately this did not help.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it uses OpenMP or it might use OpenMP (but was not compiled so)?

Comment: I am not sure if scikit-learn compiles against openmp. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/setup.py suggest not

Comment: I don't see any OpenMP `pragma` directives in the source. Only the `libsvm` wrapper seems to include `omp.h` but this looks more like template code as OpenMP is not used at all.

Comment: libsvm (version 3.1) does not use OpenMP - it only suggests how OpenMP can be supported (see FAQ and search for "pragma omp").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no OpenMP support in the current binding for libsvm in scikit-learn. However it is very likely that if you have performance issues with `sklearn.svm.SVC` should you use a more scalable model instead.

If your data is high dimensional it might be linearly separable. In that case it is advised to first try simpler models such as naive bayes models or `sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron` that are known to be very speedy to train. You can also try `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` and `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC` both implemented using `liblinear` that is more scalable than `libsvm` albeit less memory efficients than other linear models in scikit-learn.

If your data is not linearly separable, you can try `sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier` (adjust the `n_estimators` parameter to trade-off training speed vs. predictive accuracy).

Alternatively you can try to approximate a RBF kernel using the `RBFSampler` transformer of scikit-learn + fitting a linear model on the output:

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/kernel_approximation.html

Comment: thanks. my data only has 3 features. 220000 samples and 3 targets. libsvm works well on smaller samples (30k). I ended up using a Random Forest which has n_job since the data is not linearly separable.

Comment: The [SMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization) optimizer of libsvm has a complexity between `n_samples^2` and `n_samples^3` hence is not scalable to more than a couple 10k samples in practice. Random Forests and Extremely Randomized Trees (which is a Random Forests variant that generally yields slightly better results) are more scalable as long as the data fits in memory (for scikit-learn).

Comment: Larger problems will often require out-of-core / streaming non-linear feature extraction followed by a linear models incrementally updated possibly using averaging with several machines.

It is also be possible to train trees on random subsamples of the dataset in parallel on separate machines and aggregate the trees as a single random forest model (bagging). But this is not yet implemented in scikit-learn.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cross validation or grid search in scikit-learn then you can use multiple CPUs with the n_jobs parameter:

```
GridSearchCV(..., n_jobs=-1)
cross_val_score(..., n_jobs=-1)
```

Note that cross_val_score only needs a job per forld so if your number of folds is less than your CPUs you still won't be using all of your processing power.

LibSVM can use OpenMP if you can compile it and use it directly as per [these instructions in the LibSVM FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f432). So you could export your scaled data in LibSVM format (here's a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301191/python-program-to-export-numpy-lists-in-svmlight-format) on how to do that) and use LibSVM directly to train your data. But that will only be of benefit if you're grid searching or wanting to know accuracy scores, as far as I know the model LibSVM creates cannot be used in scikit-learn.

There is also a [GPU accelerated version of LibSVM](http://mklab.iti.gr/project/GPU-LIBSVM) which I have tried and is extremely fast, but is not based on the current LibSVM version. I have talked to the developers and they say they hope to release a new version soon.

Answer (score 2):

Although this thread is a year+ old, I thought it is worth answering.

I wrote a patch for openmp support on scikit-learn for both libsvm and liblinear (linearSVC) that's available here - https://github.com/fidlr/sklearn-openmp.

It is based on libsvm's FAQ on how to add OpenMP support, and the multi-core implementation of liblinear.

Just clone the repo and run sklearn-build-openmp.sh to apply the patch and build it.

Timing `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 python plot_permutation_test_for_classification.py`:

- svmlib with linear kernel timinig dropped by a factor of 2.3
- RBF kernel - same.
- Liblinear with 4 thread dropped by x1.6

Details about and usage information can be found here -
http://fidlr.org/post/137303264732/scikit-learn-017-with-libsvm-openmp-support

Comment: @fidlr I have installed your patch, I have created a python3 virtual environment and tried to install your scikit-learn patch in this environment.  However, I am getting an error: ` from . import libsvm, liblinear
ImportError: /home/es/my-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/liblinear.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: daxpy_` . Can you tell me what is this?