# H2O and Pandas SparseDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, h2o

In the Python API for the machine learning library H2O, what is the correct way to convert a sparse Pandas DataFrame object to an H2OFrame object?

Answer (score 1):

The [recommended way](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3141/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/frame.html) appears to be to save your data as an SVMLight file, then use:

```
yourFrame = h2o.import_file(path="/path/to/test.svmlight")
```

See also this answer (for R): https://stackoverflow.com/a/32877906/841830

And for exporting to svmlight from panda: https://github.com/coreylynch/sklearn-transform

Comment: This exporting package only supports categorical variables. Are you aware of a package that supports continuous variables as well?

Comment: There is this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9301191/841830  Does that help?